# How to access java scriplet varible from external java script file?

Tags: javascript, scriptlet

I have a variable defined in my.jsp file.

```
        <%String myvarible = "testing";%>
```

my.js is imported into my.jsp (just before the end of body). I try to access the myvarible in my.js. I tries several methods on the internet. But failed.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I put the assign variable on some `data-attribute` of some html tag. Then I can access it on my `js` file.

**my.jsp**

```
<div class="foo" data-jsp-variable="<%= myvariable %>"></div>
```

**my.js**

```
var bar = $('.foo').data('jsp-variable')
```